# Getting 404 Not Found error when including scripts using Node.js

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, express

I have node server and html file, where the route will be directed by default.

**server.js**

```
/**
 * Created by Nutty Programmer on 10/26/2015.
 */
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

/*
 * Configure MySQL parameters.
 */
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : "localhost",
    user : "root",
    password : "",
    database : "two_way_demo"
});

connection.connect(function(error){
    if(error)
    {
        console.log("Problem with MySQL"+error);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Connected with Database");
    }
});

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
    //res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/', 'index.html'));
    //res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '/') });
});

app.get('/load',function(req,res){
    connection.query("SELECT * from user_info",function(err,rows){
        if(err)
        {
            console.log("Problem with MySQL"+err);
        }
        else
        {
            res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
   console.log("Start listening on port 3000");
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>hello world</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

When I am trying to add angular.js in html. It gives 404 Not found error.

```
Header:
Remote Address:[::1]:3000
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/angular.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

What should be the current path?

Comment: Are you using Express ? Your angular.js file should be in /public/javascript or similar directory, which is the default directory searched

Comment: @avrono I am using express, and on project root directory have files: server.js, index.html, angular folder>angular.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to serve up static content with express you need to do something like...

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../'));
```

where the arg to express.static is the dir with your static content.